# Testing for statistical significance of the true positive detection rate between different machine learning models

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, binomial-distribution, assumptions, post-hoc

**Background**

Currently I am working on true positive detection for an image analysis problem. I have 4 methods and would like to test which methods differ from each other.

**Description of Data**

For each patient I have the number of false positives and true positives per method.

**What have I tried?**

I have looked through Andy Field's Discovering statistics using SPSS. According to this book I would have to run a one way repeated measures ANOVA. However, this would tell me that the group means differ significantly, but not what post hoc test to run.

**Questions**

1. What test would be best suited for this problem?
2. Given the right test, what assumptions would I have to test for?

Comment: You have data on true positives and false positives. What about true negatives and false negatives? Are the effective costs of all mis-classifications the same or are, say, false negatives more costly than false positives in some sense?

Comment: We get the true postive, false positive and false negative detections by calculating the connected components in the ground truth and predicted segmentation maps. If the number of overlapping voxels between a connected component in both maps is greater than some threshold it is counted as atrue positive. If a connected component in the ground truth map has insufficient overlap with those in the predicted map it is counted as a false negative, vice versa it is counted as a false positive. True negatives cannot be calculated from this.

Comment: Also the weighting of each is not important. The model development is already complete, I am only looking for the correct statistical test.

Answer (score 1):

If all you care about is the proportion of binary "true positives" estimated by 4 different methods, then you have a pretty simply logistic regression model.* The binary outcome for the regression would be success/failure, with a "true positive" being a success and all other results being failures.

The 4 methods would be treated as 4 levels of a single categorical predictor variable. As the different methods evidently evaluate all the same images/patients, you need to take the repeated measures on the same images/patients into account. Treating the images/patients as random effects within a mixed-effect model would be a way to handle that. That's analogous to the "one way repeated measures ANOVA" that you mention, but uses an analysis that's suited to binary yes/no outcomes. The links about "mixed effect models" on [this UCLA web page](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/other/dae/) can provide guidance.

If the model indicates a significant association of your categorical `method` predictor with outcome, then you have evidence that the methods do differ. A simple post-hoc comparison would be to do all 6 pairwise comparisons between the 4 methods with Wald tests, then do a correction for the [multiple comparisons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_comparisons_problem).

That type of analysis should be possible with standard software packages. Otherwise, the 3 comparisons of other methods against the reference level of `method` would typically be reported directly in the summary output of the model. Comparisons of the non-reference levels against each other would use the modeled coefficient covariance matrix together with the formula for the [variance of a weighted sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Weighted_sum_of_variables).

---

*As indicated in my comment, I'm not so sure that a sole focus on true positives is wise. This is how to proceed if you are nevertheless convinced that it is.

Comment: Thank you for your response!